# I am looking for a pc monitor for someone with visual impairment

Tags: monitors

I have a colleague who needs an additional monitor during presentations in the meeting room (the main beamer screen is too far/hard to see).

In a video from Microsoft I saw they used monitors that were somewhat 'laying' on the table. Does anyone know what type of monitor this is?

video: https://youtu.be/Z2Fw6-2fCWU?t=89
Watch @ 1:30
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure about this particular model but this is very close:

[Planar Helium PCT2785 27" Widescreen Multi-Touch Monitor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00937115E)

Take a look here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMuxpMk3gow&t=0m38s

Other examples:

1. [Dell 21.5-inches Multi-Touch Monitor with IPS S2240T](http://www.ipmart.com.my/main/product/Dell_21_5_inches_Multi_Touch_Monitor_with_IPS_S2240T_Dell_Warranty_421253.php?prod=421253)
2. [Acer FT200HQL bmjj 19.5-Inch HD+ 1600 x 900 Touchscreen Monitor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00GOBD2WW)
3. [Dell S2240T 21.5-Inch Touch Screen LED-lit Monitor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CTODKIO)
4. [Planar PXL2430MW 24" Widescreen Multi-Touch LED Monitor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0053YJZ4U)

Comment: Thanks, I never thought of looking for a touch monitor. We'll probably go with a 27" touch.